# Thinking sphinx 3 and sphinx 2.1.1-beta not start

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I install Thinking sphinx 3 on Rails 3 app and new sphinx 2.1.1-beta, before this i have 
Thinking sphinx 2 and sphinx 2.1.1-beta, and they work fine with add `port: 3312` in `sphinx.yml`

But now when i add `port: 3312` in `thinking_sphinx.yml` i get result

```
rake ts:start

Failed to start searchd daemon. Check myapp/log/development.searchd.log.

Failed to start searchd. Check the log files for more information.
```

*development.searchd.log.*

```
[Wed May 15 12:17:34.010 2013] [ 2480] binlog: replaying log /myapp/tmp/binlog/development/binlog.001

[Wed May 15 12:17:34.010 2013] [ 2480] binlog: replay stats: 0 rows in 0 commits; 0 updates; 0 indexes

[Wed May 15 12:17:34.010 2013] [ 2480] binlog: finished replaying /myapp/tmp/binlog/development/binlog.001; 0.0 MB in 0.000 sec

[Wed May 15 12:17:34.011 2013] [ 2480] binlog: finished replaying total 10 in 0.001 sec

[Wed May 15 12:17:34.012 2013] [ 2480] FATAL: listen() failed: Address already in use

[Wed May 15 12:17:34.455 2013] [ 2480] shutdown complete

[Wed May 15 12:17:34.469 2013] [ 2479] Child process 2480 has been finished, exit code   1. Watchdog finishes also. Good bye!
```

And wheh i delete `port: 3312` in `thinking_sphinx.yml` i get

*development.searchd.log.*

```
[Wed May 15 12:23:44.040 2013] [ 2527] Child process 2528 has been forked

[Wed May 15 12:23:44.389 2013] [ 2528] listening on 127.0.0.1:9306

[Wed May 15 12:23:44.390 2013] [ 2528] bind() failed on 127.0.0.1, retrying...

[Wed May 15 12:24:20.446 2013] [ 2528] FATAL: bind() failed on 127.0.0.1: Address already in use

[Wed May 15 12:24:20.478 2013] [ 2527] Child process 2528 has been finished, exit code 1. Watchdog finishes also. Good bye!
```

Comment: I has the similar issue and resolved it by removing existing searchd processes. (Run `ps aux | grep searchd`, and `kill -9 [process_id]`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `port` setting is now [`mysql41`](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/advanced_config.html) (as TS v3 uses Sphinx's Mysql41 protocol instead of the old binary protocol). Change it to that, make sure you don't have any old searchd processes running, and that should take care of things.

Comment: WTF? Why is `port` now named `mysql41` ? After an update of ThinkingSphinx I always had the error `Failed to start searchd` and `bind() failed on 127.0.0.1, retrying...` until I noticed the renaming. It took me an hour today >:(

Comment: The existing `port` setting is tied to Sphinx's old binary protocol. I realise the `mysql41` name is certainly not obvious (and, had I the chance to go back and do it differently, I perhaps would have called it something else), but I didn't want to remove the option for setting the binary port as well. Sphinx can operate both protocols at the same time, after all.

Comment: Also: it might be worth reading through the upgrading docs - this is something that's covered there, and there may be other changes you're not aware of: http://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/upgrading.html